# Load content doesn't work on Android 2.3.7 device

Tags: cordova, jqmobi, appframework

I have a mobile app developed using Intel's App Framework 2.0, App Framework MVC and Phonegap 3.2. When I tap on a link, MVC executes an action where I use the $.ui.loadContent function to show the next panel, but it doesn't seem to work properly on Android 2.3.7, because it only displays the mask that shows a "Loading Content" message, but the panel is not displayed. What could be the cause of this behavior, and how can I solve it, in order to show another panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the issue is not related to the `$.ui.loadContent` function, but to the routing. In some earlier versions of Android, and Google Chrome, when the link is put like this:

```
<a href="/mycontroller/myaction/param1">Link</a>
```

The webview/browser tries to open a local file (file:///path/to/app/mycontroller/myaction/param1), and AppFramework is not able to handle the route and execute the related action.

An ugly, but useful solution, is to execute javascript to invoke the action:

```
<a href="javascript:$.mvc.route('/mycontroller/myaction/param1');">Link</a>
```

A more elegant but heavier solution in terms of performance, could be to rewrite all the routes of the links to invoke the javascript function on init.

Answer (score 0):

I've said this many times, and many times it is the issue.

jqmobi/appframework is very specific to order. If something is not called in the right order (css,js, functions) it will budge on some platforms. Not a clue why (specifically), but it seems to be it every time.

Try and reordering every script and function to match the example. More then once that worked for me.